# How to compare a list of data from a text file to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, fstream

I am making a program to calculate student's score. I have data stored inside a text file (fstream) that contains student id and their answer (True/False). Then, I want the program to compare the student's answer inside the file with the correct one (stored inside array) and if it is matched, score will +1 and if not score will -1. (Comparing T/F char by char)

So, for the correct answer of the test I store it inside array.
eg: `char ans[5]={'T','F','T','F','T'}`

How to compare **each line** of data inside the file (student's answer) with the array (correct answer)? I just need some hints, right now I don't even know how to start the code yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Count the number of differences?

Comment: @BaummitAugen if it match, i will add 1 point and if not will deduct 1

Comment: Just read it and [compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) it?

Comment: It seems like a `bool` array would be a good choice. Use one bool per question/answer. Then, XOR tells you where a wrong answer is, and "count ones" tells you how many wrong answers.

Comment: Go ahead and submit your code and we will comment on it...

Comment: What is `18000`? is that the score you want to increase for correct answers?

Comment: @Ayxan thats student id

Comment: Sorry for not explaining enough. What I meant was compare the student's answer with the correct one and if it is matched, score will +1 and if not score will -1. I know how to do with the score but do not have any idea with comparing array of the correct answer with the student's answer inside a text file(fstream)

Answer (score 1):

You can read files using file streams in [`<fstream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream).

Once the file open, you can use `>>` exactly as you would do from the console.

You can then read the student's answers as a string (e.g.`"FFTTF"`).  To verify the results, you need to do loop, comparing successively each character of the string at index `[i]`  with the item of your array at the same index.

Increment the score by one for every successful match and you ahve the score.

***Note:*** I won't produce code in order not to spoil your homework.  If you edit your question showing what you have tried, you'd get more responses